# Использование Nullable в паттернах

Tags: c#, nullable

Почему `a is T b`, где `T` это `Nullable<int>` можно, а `a is Nullable<int> b` нельзя?

```csharp
   class Program
   {
      static T foo<T>(T a, T c) => (a is T b) ? b : c;

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Nullable<int> t1 = foo<Nullable<int>>(123, 456);

         Nullable<int> a = 123;
         Nullable<int> c = 456;
         Nullable<int> t2 = (a is Nullable<int> b) ? b : c; // эта строка не компилируется
      }
   }
```

Comment: А что пишет в ошибке компиляции? Может там что-то полезное написано?

Comment: @CrazyElf `It is not legal to use nullable type 'int?' in a pattern; use the underlying type 'int' instead.`

Comment: @CrazyElf, на .NET Framwork 4.6.1 C# 7.3 пишет "error CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected" и "error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'"

Comment: @Андрей там в тернар операторе не понимает синтаксис `int?`, но его можно заменить на `Nullable<int>`. В таком случае компиляция выдаст вышеупомянутую ошибку.

Comment: Потому что такая проверка бессмысленна. `NULL` не является типом, а вы сейчас пытаетесь сделать что-то типа "Является `a` типом `int` или `null`". Если сверяете типы, то и сверяйте `int`.

Comment: ¿4.6.1 это же C# 6? Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342949

Comment: Что должна возвращать **foo<int?>** в зависимости от того **а** null или нет и почему?

Comment: А при чем тут `foo`? Строка, которая дает вам ошибку вообще не связана с `foo`, обобщением, и чем либо еще. Ошибка у вас тут `(a is int? b)`, где вы сравниваете не тип, а по сути его обертку, ну а сам тип это просто `int`, вот и пишите `(a is int b)`. Почему нельзя так, как вы хотите, выше отличная ссылка.